# typescript mapping destructured parameter with type gives error

Tags: typescript, destructuring

Lets say I have the following object

```
const a = {
   history: string[]
}
```

Now I am trying to assign history using to another variable historyMapped giving the object type (string[]) as well.

```
const { history: mappedCareerHistory }: { mappedCarerHistory: string[] } = a;
```

However I'm getting the following error here

**property mappedHistory is missing in type.....**

If I simply remove the type and then include the following it works without a compilation issue

```
const { history: mappedCareerHistory } = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because you are unwrapping object not changing key.

**For Ex**

```
let a = {history:['1','2']};
const {history: mappedCareerHistory} = a;
console.log(mappedCareerHistory); // ["1", "2"];
```

You are not changing the key of the object you are unwrapping the object so compiler giving errors. so type must be a string array not mapped object type.

Comment: taking your above example then how do I give a type to the mappedCareerHistory?

Comment: can you specify what behavior exactly you want ?